# How to make some pages not require authentication in Symfony

Tags: symfony

Currently, any page I go to in my Symfony2 web app well direct the user to log in (if they aren't already logged in). This is okay - except there is one set of pages (my webservices, which will be under /webservice/*) which I don't want to force authentication from. Because it is a JSON webservice that will not be user facing, obviously I don't want it trying to redirect to a log in form.

This is my current security.yml firewall:

```
firewalls:
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

login:
    pattern:  ^/$
    security: false

secured_area:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        check_path: my_app_authentication_login
        login_path: my_app_authentication_homepage
        username_parameter: form[username]
        password_parameter: form[password]
        default_target_path: my_app_task_homepage
        always_use_default_target_path: true
    logout:
        path: my_app_authentication_logout
        target: my_app_authentication_homepage
```

What do I have to do to make /webservice/* exempt from authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add to your `security.yml` file (this must be before your `secured_area`, order matters):

```
your_whatever_name:
    pattern: ^/webservice/
    security: false
```

Check [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) for more info

Comment: Also available IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY which just means that the route is for users who aren't logged in.

Comment: I actually did try adding `      - { path: ^/webservice, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` to access_control, but that didn't work. Does the ordering matter for that? Because access_control is below the firewalls in my yml file.